# Firebase Realtime Database Rules checking for array contains

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My auth token includes a `stores` property. This property is an Array that includes ID's of all stores the user is allowed to access. For example:
`stores: ['abc123', 'def456']`.

Now, in my Firebase Realtime Database, I am saving store specific data like this:

```
{
  "stores": {
    "abc123": {
      "data": "mydata"
    },
    "def456": {
      "data": "mydata"
    }
  }
}
```

Users are allowed to access the realtime database data if their `stores` property array includes the storeID specific data they want to access.

What I would like my rules to look like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "stores": {
      "$store_id": {
        ".read": "auth.token.stores.includes($store_id)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is not possible. I get the following error:

`Error saving rules - line 5: type error: function call on target that is not a function.`

Is it possible to search trough token property arrays in the firebase rules or will I have to use an object? Thanks for any answers!

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 6):

Firebase Realtime Database does not have any `includes()` to check if a value if present in an array or not. You can store the claims as a map instead of an array as shown below:

```
// custom claims
{
  stores: {
    store1: true,
    store2: true,
    store3: false
  }
}
```

Then you can use the following rules to check if user has access to a particular store or no:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "stores": {
      "$store_id": {
        ".read": "auth.token.stores[$store_id] == true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I already thought that it wouldn't be possible... Not being able to check through arrays in the RT Rules is a big miss on Firebase's site tho

Comment: Agreed - doubly annoying if I want a bidirectional association. If $uid1 can access $uid2's values given they're in an associated list, and $uid2 can also access $uid1s values, then there has to be both uid1: uid2 as well as uid2:uid1 in the list.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `in` operator from [List](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List)

> v in x
> Check if value v exists in list x.

```
'a' in ['a','b'] == true
```

Sample Security Rules how it can be done

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      
      match /stores/{storeId} {
        allow read: if isAuthenticated() && isUserAllowed();
      }
      
      function isAuthenticated() {
        return request.auth != null;
      }

      function isUserAllowed() {
        return request.auth.uid in resource.data.stores
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: OP is using [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database) but your answer has security rules for [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore)

Comment: Oh I missed that @Dharmaraj